# Finding Non Repeating Record

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two table one is called licenses And One is called systems.
Now license table hold system id and license type (full or trial).
And systems table hold system mac_address.

Now one system may have more than one trial licenses and one full license.
Now i want to find systems whose full version haven't generated yet with grouping them along with their mac_address .

Please little suggestion would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select 
    s.*
from
    systems as s 
where
    s.system_id not in 
    (select l.system_id from licenses as l where l.licence_type='full')
```

Comment: quite nearly but it also show record of trial version generated for the same mac_address...

Comment: Thanx u so much according to your ans i did some hack and finally i got result what i wanted.
thank you sir.

Comment: select 
       system.*,
       License.*
 from
       licenses as License 
 inner join system as systems on  ystems.id = License.system_id 
 WHERE 
       system.mac_address NOT IN 
       (
         select system.mac_address from licenses as lic 
              inner join system as s on 
                 lic.system_id = s.id 
           where lic.license_type = 'Full'
       )


Using this query i got my result.

Comment: @DipeshParmar I don't know how efficient that answer is. My solution should provide the same results and might be more efficient (it's certainly more readable!)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you, you need to find all systems that don't have a "full" licence listed. In pure SQL you can achieve this using a LEFT JOIN. Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.system_id,s.mac_address
FROM systems s
LEFT JOIN licences l ON s.system_id=l.system_id AND l.licence_type = 'full'
WHERE l.licence_id IS NULL
```

Comment: yes sir but using my answered query i found result what i wished to get.
And i also thankful that ur ans also gave me idea about getting what i intended to get.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your question but can't you make one of the columns unique?

Comment: i cant cause i need to manage systems and their licenses according to their mac_address.
now system can be added more than once with same mac_address but different register keys.
so i need to track all information.